# Twisted Python: reactor and protocol

Tags: python, protocols, twisted, reactor

I have several questions about the Twisted reactor.

1/ What kind of errors would crash/stop/terminate the reactor? what kind of errors would not?

2/ I have two reactors, each running a different protocol. I have protocols A and B.

One reactor creates a new instance of protocol A every time it handles an input. If there is an error in an instance of protocol A, that error only affects the instance, and the reactor keeps running smoothly.

The other reactor runs only ONE instance of protocol B (specifically I use it to handle standard IO). It is simply like this:

```
stdio.StandardIO(ProtocolB())
reactor.run()
```

If an input somehow gives an error in Protocol B, then it affects the entire reactor. Does the reactor actually stop in that case?

3/ In the case of the second reactor above, is it possible to create a new instance of protocol B to replace the old instance if an error is detected?

Answer (score 2):

> 1/ What kind of errors would crash/stop/terminate the reactor? what
>   kind of errors would not?

A rule of thumb is: `reactor` runs until `reactor.stop()` is called by you or in response to an expected event e.g., SIGINT signal (keyboard interrupt).

> If an input somehow gives an error in Protocol B, then it affects the
>   entire reactor. Does the reactor actually stop in that case?

No, exceptions in your code won't stop the reactor:

```
import sys
from twisted.internet import reactor, task

def raise_exception():
    raise RuntimeError
reactor.callWhenRunning(raise_exception)

task.LoopingCall(sys.stderr.write, '.').start(.4) # heartbeat
reactor.callLater(5, reactor.stop) # stop reactor
reactor.run()
```

> 2/ I have two reactors, each running a different protocol. I have
>   protocols A and B.

There should be only one reactor whatever number of protocols is.

> 3/ In the case of the second reactor above, is it possible to create a
>   new instance of protocol B to replace the old instance if an error is
>   detected?

You can but you shouldn't do it. if `connectionMade`, `lineReceived`  raise exceptions it is a bug and you should fix it.

Here's an example that relaunches after exception. It is just a demonstration that it is possible, *don't use it* in a actual code.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

prompt = ">>>> "
class ReverseLineProtocol(LineReceiver):
    delimiter = '\n'

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("Write everything in reverse.")
        self.transport.write(prompt)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if line == 'raise':
            reactor.callLater(1, launch)
            raise RuntimeError
        self.sendLine(line[::-1])
        self.transport.write(prompt)

def launch():
    StandardIO(ReverseLineProtocol())

launch()
reactor.run()
```